# Cron Debugger not Working

Tags: magento2, cron, debugging, xdebug

Can anybody tell me how Can I use debugger on the Cron.

I tried to do many things, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Take a look at https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/294931/519

Comment: do you want to try xdebug?

Comment: Yes I want to debug by xdebugger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Might Help You

i expect You have configured xdebug on Your Project

Now Add a New Debug Configurations Like this

[image]

Now You can Run the Cli command Like this

```
XDEBUG_TRIGGER=yes php bin/magento cron:run
```

I hope this will help You

Comment: I configured everything, But When I run this command 
" XDEBUG_TRIGGER=yes php bin/magento cron:run"  Debugger is not working on the Cron

Comment: what is schedule for your cron job?

Comment: just set this : * * * * * I am running by the just command to run the cron at any time

Answer (score 0):

You can use a logger to debug cron.

**If you are using logger for only testing purpose, you can use direct code either use proper magento standard**

**With Magento 2.4.4 & plus versions use below code:**

```
$writer = new \Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(BP . '/var/log/testing.log');
$logger = new \Zend_Log();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('Test the log');
$logger->info(var_dump($yourVariable));
```

**For Magento 2.4.2 & lower versions:**

```
$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/custom.log');
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('Custom message'); 
$logger->info(var_dump($yourVariable));
```

**UPDATE:**

Try below:

**As mentioned by MagePal Extensions in your comment.**

Create a new file, for example, test.php, and put it in your magento2 pub directory with the following code:

You have to replace `NameSpace\YourClassName` `with your cron class`. And then hit this file in browser to debug the code for cron. Your cron will execute by hitting this file on browser.

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php';

class TestMyClass
    extends \Magento\Framework\App\Http
    implements \Magento\Framework\AppInterface
{
    public function launch()
    {
        $this->_state->setAreaCode(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_ADMINHTML);
        $myClass = $this->_objectManager->create('NameSpace\YourClassName');
        $myClass->execute(); // In cron jobs we usually use the execute() method as the entry point
        return $this->_response;
    }
}

$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('TestMyClass');
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

Comment: I am using these logs but I want to use debugger on the cron

Comment: You should use xdebugger, for that you need to configure xdebug in your Code editor and set enpoints to start debugging.

Comment: I configured and using but xdeugger not working on the crons

Comment: @RanaZain I have updated my answer please check that